# Lifecycle node consuming cpu in deactivated state

Tags: ros2, rclcpp, spinning

My node which is a critical component of a larger system contains the following interfaces for communicating with other nodes

1. Two action servers
2. One tf listner
3. One service server
4. Four subscribers
5. Two publishers

[running in ros 2 foxy in docker container]

I recently implemented the lifecycle version of this node and the idea was to deactivate the node when not required and save on CPU usage. I followed the following practices while implementing the lifecycle version:

- Defined all parameters in constructor of class
- Initializing pubs,subs,srvers etc all in on_configure callback.
- Activating things which could be activated in on_activate callback and controlling rest with bools
- Deactivating things which could be deactivated in on_deactivate callback and resetting the bools for all others
- resetting all pointers in cleanup

My external code which controls the lifecycle of this node uses `activate` and `deactivate` states while in operation and `configure` / `cleanup` only once per run.

The CPU usage before `on_configure` is less than 1% which is expected. It goes to 15% on `configure` but it doesn't change much on `activate` or `deactivate`.
(The compute might be going in spinnig and waiting i guess but not sure)

so activating and deactivating is not really giving me what i needed.
I tried moving a few things from cleanup and configure into deactivate and activate CBs and got some improvement like the tf_listner it saved me around 4-5% of cpu. But the rest is still being utilized under the hood in spinning I guess.

Can we do anything else to reduce the usage further ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to speculate its your TF system. TF is not a lifecycle system, so unless you're resetting the TF buffer / listener in `on_deactivate`, you're still processing incoming transformation information. Also, subscribers similarly have no lifecycle eq. I'd look at resetting those in on_deactivate as well.

Comment: Yes, the tf_listner was taking some of the usage and after resetting it saved 4-5%.  I'll try  resetting the subscribers too. what about service and action servers? should they be reset as well?